# Friends not showing up in "My Circles" in Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I am working on a game for Android devices with Google Play integration. The app is ready for testing on the Google Play Developer console, and scores are being reported successfully.

The other developers have been added as testers and we are friends on Google+. However, they do not appear as players in the "My Circles" section of the leaderboard pop-up. They do show in the public section.

Is this a known issue? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple months late, but, considering I've recently run into the exact same problem, I figure I'll post my findings to aid anyone who stumbles upon this question in the future.

Since the app is "ready for testing," I assume that it hasn't been published. **Publishing is the key**.  There are two tiny sentences buried in a NOTE on this Google developer page:

https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/leaderboards#creating_a_leaderboard

> Note: Social leaderboards will initially be empty until you publish
>   the corresponding leaderboard by using the Google Play Developer
>   Console

Social leaderboards won't be useful until **after** you publish. i.e. You'll never see social leaderboards during testing.